# How can I send text from a document (.txt) to an ESP32 via the Websocket-client library in Python?

Tags: python, websocket, display, sendmessage

I have tried out programming python for a few weeks, and I am currently trying to send text from a document to an ESP32 module so that I can show this text on a display. The program I am using on the ESP32 works, but when I try using the websocket-client library to send the text it doesn't.

This is my code:

```
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://10.0.0.178/test")

datei = open('text.txt', 'r')
print(datei.read())

ws.send('Hi')

ws.close()
datei.close()
```

This Code lets me see "Hi" on my display and the text from the file in the local terminal.

If I put

```
ws.send(datei.read())
```

instead of

```
ws.send('Hi')
```

then I cannot see anything on the display.

Am I using the function wrong? If I do, can someone tell me how it actually works?

Comment: Drop the `print()` it does nothing but printing to the local terminal. And don't read the file twice.